# Finding Static Friction of Car Going Around Curve

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

> The question is: A 1200 kg car is traveling along a curve 250m in radius and is moving at a speed of 10m/s but is lowing at a rate of 2m/s^2. What is the static friction force on the car as a fraction of its weight at that instant.

I'm confused what significance the acceleration plays since it doesn't fit into the equations obviously.

What I tried:

Finding the angle tan(x) = (10m/s)^2/(250m*9.8m/s^2)

This gives an angle of 2.3 degrees.

Then I find the normal force. mg = Fn*cos(x)

I find Fn to be 11769N. I divide this by the weight and get the incorrect answer.

Comment: What is the angle that forms part of your solution?

Comment: The angle I found (not given) is 2.3 degrees

Comment: What does the angle measure?  There is no mention of any angle in the question.

Comment: In order to find the normal force which equals the Fsf times coefficient of static friction I need the angle.

Comment: mv^2/r = Fnsin(x) and mg = Fncos(x)

Comment: You have quoted the formula for a car driving without friction around a banked curve.  Why do you believe that the curve is banked?

Comment: Oh...bingo. Well the textbook only provided that formula, but a quick google search helped me find the static friction force of .04N. Is this reasonable? v^2/(rg) for the formula.

So now I have to find how much it weighs during that acceleration period...any tips there?

Comment: I mean static friction force is 470N, the coefficient of static friction is .04

Answer (score 1):

The car is experiencing acceleration in two perpendicular directions.

At the moment in question, the car is moving at the given velocity in a circle with the given radius.  You have the formula for the centripetal force needed, and this is supplied by the **radial** force of friction.

The car is also slowing down with the given acceleration. This requires a **tangential** force, given by Newton's Second Law.

Combine these two forces with Pythagoras to find the total force size and direction.